# Flask-SQLAlchemy how to delete all rows in a single table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I delete all rows in a single table using Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Looking for something like this:

```
>>> users = models.User.query.all()
>>> models.db.session.delete(users)

# but it errs out: UnmappedInstanceError: Class '__builtin__.list' is not mapped
```

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Try [`delete`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete):

```
models.User.query.delete()
```

From [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete): `Returns the number of rows deleted, excluding any cascades.`

Comment: Hmm, this worked for me, but only after changing it to something like this: `models.User.query().delete()`

Comment: Does not work if you use a query like this:
`Model.query.filter(Model.some_id == some_id, Model.other_id.in_(other_ids).delete()`

Comment: Don't forget to commit after deleting.

Comment: If you are using `Flask-SQLAlchemy` then try `User.query.delete()` as `query` object as 'BaseQuery' object is not callable. Tested and verified.

Answer (score 146):

DazWorrall's answer is spot on. Here's a variation that might be useful if your code is structured differently than the OP's:

```
num_rows_deleted = db.session.query(Model).delete()
```

Also, don't forget that the deletion won't take effect until you commit, as in this snippet:

```
try:
    num_rows_deleted = db.session.query(Model).delete()
    db.session.commit()
except:
    db.session.rollback()
```

Answer (score 91):

### Flask-Sqlalchemy

**Delete All Records**

```
#for all records
db.session.query(Model).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

**Deleted Single Row**

here DB is the object Flask-SQLAlchemy class. It will delete all records from it and if you want to delete specific records then try `filter` clause in the query.
ex.

```
#for specific value
db.session.query(Model).filter(Model.id==123).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

**Delete Single Record by Object**

```
record_obj = db.session.query(Model).filter(Model.id==123).first()
db.session.delete(record_obj)
db.session.commit()
```

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#deleting-records

Comment: I am in a similar kind of a situation. Say there are 4 records in the table as of now, from id 1 to 4. When I do a db.session.query(Table_name).delete() db.session.commit() and then if I do a db.session.add() again to add new records, the next record gets an id of 5. Since my table is now empty, I want my new records to now get an id starting from 1 again. How can I do this ?

Comment: Please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038422/reset-id-count-after-table-delete

Answer (score 0):

writing raw sql commands sometimes is useful

```
    def delete_table_content(self, table_name: str):
          "deletes table contents"
          CONNECTION = db_url
          conn = psycopg2.connect(CONNECTION)
          conn.autocommit = True
          cursor = conn.cursor()
          cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE {}".format(table_name))
          logger.warning("deleted table {} content".format(table_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have an application with several types of tables, I pass the ID and TYPE in the URL of the delete button like this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('app.cleartable',type='items') }}" class="btn btn-danger">
    <i class="fas fa-trash fa-fw"></i>
    Clear table
</a>
```

now if you make the request to `'/delete/<string:type>/<int:id>'` the value of the text string will be taken to do the deletion and redirect to the following `url` in **items**

```
@app.route('/delete/<string:type>/<int:id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def delete(type, id):
    if type == "item":
        to_delete = Item.query.get(id)

        try:
            db.session.delete(to_delete)
            db.session.commit()
            flash(f'{to_delete.name} successfully deleted!', 'success')
        except:
            db.session.rollback() 
            flash(f'{to_delete.name} failed to delete!', 'error')
        return redirect(url_for('items'))
```