# Reset id count after table delete()

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For testing purposes, I clear (delete) every table before executing code.

```
for table in reversed(db.metadata.sorted_tables):
    engine.execute(table.delete())

do_stuff()
```

However, the new data's `id` values start from where the previous `id`'s left off:

First iteration:

```
 id  | value   
-----+---------
 1   | hi      
 2   | there
```

Second iteration (delete table, insert new data):

```
 id  | value   
-----+---------
 3   | good    
 4   | day
```

Is there any way to reset the `id` count when I delete the table?

---

EDIT: seems I broke it, table is not cleared at all now

```
config.py

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://postgres:myPassword@localhost/myDatabase'


app.py

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


models.py

from app import app, db

def clear():
    for table in reversed(db.metadata.sorted_tables):
        db.engine.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE ' + table.name + ' RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE')
```

The table is still being added to (using `db.session.add_all()` and `db.session.commit()`). However, `clear()` does nothing.  When I log in as the `postgres` user in `terminal` and directly execute `TRUNCATE TABLE myTable RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE`, it works.

`table.name` gives the correct names.  That leads me to believe there is something wrong with `db.engine.execute()`, but that does not make much sense since `db.session.add_all()` works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call `TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable RESTART IDENTITY;` for every table in the loop instead of calling `table.delete()` - this should reset the auto increment sequence.

Comment: In the context of my code, what would I replace `MyTable` with?  I want to delete every table in my database, so I would I have to get an array of table names?

Comment: @onepiece `MyTable` would be `table.__table__` as far as I understand. Give it a try.

Comment: Running TRUNCATE might not be allowed on the table to which there are foreign keys.

Comment: @van it will if you use `CASCADE`, e.g. following @alecxe's accepted answer you'd have:  `TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;`

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html

Comment: As much as this works, in my specific case was a LOT slower than `table.delete()` (no idea why). My solution was to only use this on one specific table where I needed predictable IDs (during integration tests).