# How to remove all rows from a SQLAlchemy relationship child table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I was thinking that this task is rather trivial, but I have no luck in googling about it. If I have a `User` table, that has `upload_list` relationships into table `Videos`, how do you clear that `upload_list` table?

I construct it this way:

```
class Users(base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(100), unique=True)
    password = Column(String(255))
    fullname = Column(String(255))
    photo = Column(String(255))
    last_updated = Column(DateTime())

    upload_lists = relationship('UploadLists', cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")


class UploadLists(base):
    __tablename__ = 'upload_lists'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    list_id = Column(String(255), unique=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship("Users")

    videos = relationship('Videos', cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")


class Videos(base):
    __tablename__ = 'videos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    video_id = Column(String(255), unique=True)
    title = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(String(255))
    upload_date = Column(DateTime)
    thumbnail_url = Column(Text())
    thumbnail_file = Column(Text())
```

Comment: Drop the table and recreate it?

Comment: .. but then all other `upload_lists` data for other users will get removed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573802/flask-sqlalchemy-how-to-delete-all-rows-in-a-single-table), the solution is pretty obvious actually. Here goes:
`s.query(models.UploadLists).filter(models.UploadLists.user_id == user.id).delete()`

But still, the above models seems to not having a proper cascading delete configuration.Deleting the `UploadList` for certain User still left all of its related videos left in table `Videos`. Working on it now, and if you know the answer, it's great that you left the answer here. I'll mark it as accepted if it's a correct answer :)