# when I do the delete operation I am getting this error 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state''

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am usinf flask,sqlalchemy and sqlite3 for my web application.
When I try to the delete operation in my table through UI  I am getting an error

```
delete_user = Usertimeslots.query.filter(Usertimelots.user_id==user_id).all()
print("i am delete",delete_user,file=sys.stderr)
db.session.delete(delete_user)
db.session.commit()
```

I am trying to delete the row where user id is same in usertimeslots tableuser id

How do I delete the row of the table through flask sqlalchemy

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573802/flask-sqlalchemy-how-to-delete-all-rows-in-a-single-table

Answer (score 1):

`Query.all()` returns a list, but `Session.delete()` expects a model instance. You'll have to apply delete on each object of the list separately in order to mark them for deletion:

```
for du in delete_user:
    db.session.delete(du)

db.session.commit()
```

or delete them all with a single bulk operation:

```
Usertimeslots.query.filter(Usertimelots.user_id==user_id).delete(synchronize_session=False)
db.session.commit()
```

If on the other hand you expect the query to match a single row only, use `Query.one()`:

```
delete_user = Usertimeslots.query.filter(Usertimelots.user_id==user_id).one()
db.session.delete(delete_user)
db.session.commit()
```